# The useContext state value doesn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I changed the value of setEvents and setNextStartHo in useEffect and printed it out in console.log, but it shows the initial value.

I created a Context called EventTimeContext. I want to change nextStartHour and event values ​​in other components.

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

export const EventTimeContext = createContext<any>({ 
 nextStartHour: 24,
 event: false,
 setNextStartHo: (nextStartHour: number) => {},
 setEvents: (event: boolean) => {},
})

export const EventTimeContextProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {

  const [nextStartHour, setNextStartHour] = useState(24);
  const [event, setEvent] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const setEvents = useCallback(
    (event: boolean) => {
      setEvent(event);
    },
    [setEvent]
  );

    const setNextStartHo = useCallback(
    (hour: number) => {
      setNextStartHour(hour);
    },
    [setNextStartHour]
  );

return (
    <EventTimeContext.Provider
      value={{
        nextStartHour,
        event,
        setEvents: setEvents,
        setNextStartHo: setNextStartHo,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </EventTimeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

In useEffect, I changed the value with the events and setNextStartHo function, but if I take a look at the console.log, it has the initial value.

```
// index.ts
const { nextStartHour, event, setEvents, setNextStartHo } = useContext(EventTimeContext);


useEffect(() => {
  setEvents(true);
  setNextStartHo(10); 
}, [])

console.log(nextStartHour); // 24 
console.log(event); // false
```

How should I solve the problem?

Comment: Does it show _only_ the initial values? I expected you to have 4 printouts in your console. 2 from the initial render, 2 from the second. Could you make a codesandbox? Also fyi: useCallback isn't necessary for useState setters.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Do you see everything ok?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with the callback wrappers around your setter functions. Why do you have those?

Comment: @BrentonHaerr The children argument isn't showing up.

Comment: @ssksksks I still don't see a codesandbox? https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @ssksksks, I still don't see what that has to do with the setter wrappers. But that's okay! I don't think it'll hurt anything.

Comment: Is the component that consumes the context being wrapped by the provider?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the `console.log(nextStartHour); // 24` call just in the body of your index.js file, so the value you get when you do your console log comes from BEFORE the rerender caused by `useEffect`. Your value should be changed, but it won't be clear from a `console.log` that's just in the main body.

If you want to see this, a good way would be to have a component with this render:

```
render(
 <>
  {nextStartHour} // this will show your 10 value if your useEffect code is in this comp.
 </>
)
```

Keep in mind that react is not the same as a straight JS/TS file. It's all about rendering. If you want a more specific example, we'll need more code--but this is what's wrong.

Comment: You have your log right after `useEffect`. `useEffect` doesn't just mean 'run right now', it means 'run when this component is mounted to the DOM.' You are running your console.log before the component is mounted (because it's just right there in your script.

Comment: The same call from useEffect produces the same result.

Comment: Yes it will. You are expecting the wrong kind of result from `useEffect`. What are you rendering with this code? Without info on what you're actually rendering, we can't know what you hope to be seeing. I recommend you read my answer again--it's right! But think about how you're rendering information. Where are you OUTPUTTING this change that you made with `useEffect`? You can't just do it in a console log in the index.ts file. You are changing state. You need to output that onto your screen using a `render`.